# How to reference an xsd-Schema in an xml-node

Tags: xml, xsd

I need to put a reference to an XML-schema (xsd) into an XML-node. It should look like this:

```
<root>
  <!--reference to xsd-->
  <child1/>
  <child2/>
</root>
```

At the place of the comment should be a link to some schema. Is there a standard way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms757863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to start reading about referencing schema documents in XML documents; it gives you a description of the two attributes, xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation and  xsi:schemaLocation used for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do something like what `schemaLocation` attribute does.

(I may have misunderstood your question though).