# How to reference XSD schema correctly?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Note: I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513825/how-to-reference-an-xsd-schema-in-an-xml-node) question but still was not able to understand how to correctly apply the information there.

I am pretty much still a newbie to XML, but have created an XML file that starts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
  <Model>
    <Name>My Configuration</Name>
    <Version>0.0.1</Version>
  </Model>
</Configuration>
```

The XSD looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema id="Configuration" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:element name="Configuration">
    <!-- and so on -->
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Now in my C# program I can validate it against a *known* XSD schema using the `XDocument.Validate()` method, and I can desearialize it using an XmlSerializer and classes generated from my XSD (using `XSD.exe`) no problem.

However I am attempting to have the XSD referenced inline in the XML, adding the 
`xsi:schemaLocation` attribute to the root `<Configuration>` element, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org file:///C:/Users/Me/Data/ConfigSchema.xsd">
```

I have the C# code building OK (using the `XmlReader.Create()` method), but it always tells me the following error message for all elements:

> Could not find schema information for the element ''.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to change something else in the XML or XSD?

**UPDATE:** I can make this work by adding an XSD `targetNamepsace` equal to the XML `xmlns` and `xsi:schemaLocation` `urn`. But then normal deserialization fails on the first element (i.e. the Configuration element containing this namespace/schema mess)

Comment: Your `Configuration` element is not in a namespace, despite all of the namespace related machinery you've tried to include.  See the duplicate link for how to properly use `xsi:schemaLocation` and `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation`.  Also, don't use a `http://www.w3.org` for your own XSDs -- use a URL that you control.  (`xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org file:///C:/Users/Me/Data/ConfigSchema.xsd"` is not what you want.  Again, see duplicate link for the proper pattern to follow.)

Comment: @kjhughes Thanks. What if i don't *have* a URL I control? This XML is never going to be used online it's more for application formatted data storage (yes, I know there are other methods that may be better suited to this, but XML is a requirement).

Comment: You could use `http://www.example.com/whatever`.

Comment: @kjhughes Is there any difference between `example.com` and `w3.org`? I don't have control of either and both have (or could have) non-XML content at a given address, right?

Comment: Nothing authorizes such use of a `w3.org`, but [**RFC2606**](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606) does authorize use of `example.com` for testing.  Note also that [**namespace URIs do not have to be retrievable**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27614076/290085).

Comment: @kjhughes Awesome, thank you Kenneth.